# Why does getline function discard the middle string?

Tags: c++11

I'm pretty new to C++ and StackOverflow.
I'm trying to get only the marks from the string which is read from the file. Whenever I tried doing it, it outputs 50 and 75 only.
Can someone explain to me why does it print only print these 2 lines only, please?

Expected output: 50,80,75

```
int main()
{
    string storeContents;
    string temp;
    string fileName("input.txt");
    ifstream inFile(fileName);

    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        getline(inFile,storeContents);
        getline(inFile,storeContents, ' ');
        getline(inFile,storeContents, ' ');
        getline(inFile,storeContents, ' ');
        getline(inFile,storeContents, '\n');
        cout << storeContents << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:
50
75

File contents:

102234 962 4

Data_Structures ICT283 3 50

Security_Policy ICT380 1 80

Programming ICT159 4 75

Comment: Consider stepping through the code in a debugger and examining the contents of `storeContents` after each read.

Comment: `getline(inFile,storeContents);` reads the whole line (and then discards it, by way of overwriting `storeContents` with the data from the following line). So on the first iteration, the loop reads and discards `102234 962 4`. then works through components of `Data_Structures ICT283 3 50`. On the second iteration, the loop reads and discards `Security_Policy ICT380 1 80`. then works through components of `Programming ICT159 4 75`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik got it thanks for the explanation but if I put a new line at the end of programming ICT159 4 75 it works fine. is it possible for you to explain to me? sorry for this, I'm really confused as to why it works

Comment: What do you mean, works fine? Does it no longer skip the `80` component? I find this difficult to believe; that would mean the code you've shown is not the code you are actually running; or else that you've altered the file contents in more ways than just adding a blank line at the end. For example, if you put a blank line after every record, your program would appear to work because `getline(inFile,storeContents);` would consume (and discard) that blank line, rather than every other record.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yup, it no longer skips the 80 component. To be honest, I altered the file contents by adding the blank line at the end of the text file and adding a blank space after each line

Comment: Like I said, your loop discards every other line. You "fixed" the problem by adding blank lines for it to discard.